# Applescript and Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, bash, eclipse-plugin, applescript, flash-builder

I'm trying to get applescript to resize and move the windows of Flash Builder but I keep getting an error does anyone know how to get Eclipse or Flash Builder to play nicely with applescript?

For example:

```
tell application "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5"
    activate
    set the bounds of the first window to {-1680, 650, 0, 1050}
end tell
```

Returns this error:

```
tell application "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5"
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {-1680, 650, 0, 1050}
        --> error number -1708
Result:
error "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 got an error: Can’t set bounds of window 1 to {-1680, 650, 0, 1050}." number -10006 from bounds of window 1
```

or maybe there is a way to do this in bash? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two error codes at play here: `-1708` and `-10006`.

`-1708` is thrown when trying to script an application that isn't scriptable. `-10006` is more generic but comes up when an object can't be set; you may not be able to set the bounds of a window via a script. Are you sure Flash Builder is actually scriptable?

Either way, bash won't help you out here. If the application doesn't support Open Scripting Architecture, there is little else you can do.

Comment: So how do I find out if Eclipse or Flash Builder is scriptable? :)

Comment: @gdoubleod: Within the Applescript Editor, go to the Menubar > `File` > `Open Dictionary...` and look for the application. If it is not listed, you can manually point the Editor to it, but chances are that if it is not in the list presented, it is not scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

As @philipregan mentions, it's because the app isn't scriptable.
To find out if an application is scriptable, follow these instructions from apple.

> To determine if a particular app is scriptable, see if it has a scripting dictionary. See [Opening a Scripting Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/OpenaScriptingDictionary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH76-SW1).

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AboutScriptingTerminology.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH9-SW1)